# "turn down the volume" or "turn the volume down" - phrasal verb structure

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm learning about phrasal verbs, but I'm not sure if I'll use them correctly.
Which one of the following phrasal verb uses correct:

> -I don't know how to **turn down** the volume?
>
> -I don't know how to **turn** the volume **down**?

I always think that they're same, but lately I feel like there must be a rule how to use them correctly, or perhaps they get different meanings?

Comment: Omg. This question me gives me a gold!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They're both fine, and they mean the same thing.  The particle *down* can appear before or after the object *the volume*:

> 1a. I don't know how to **turn** the volume **down**.
>   ​1b. I don't know how to **turn down** the volume.

However, if the object is an unstressed personal pronoun, *down* has to come at the end:

> 2a. I don't know how to **turn** it **down**.
>   2b. *I don't know how to **turn down** it.

I marked example 2b with an asterisk `*` to indicate that it's ungrammatical.

By the way, if the object is very long or complicated, *down* usually appears beforehand, because it would be confusing to keep the listener waiting to hear the rest of *turn down*:

> 3a. <sup>?</sup>I don't know how to **turn** the volume on the stereo receiver attached to the TV over there **down**.
>   3b. I don't know how to **turn down** the volume on the stereo receiver attached to the TV over there.

I marked 3a with a question mark `?` to show that, although it's grammatical, it's not a very good sentence.  With such a long object, it's better to put *down* beforehand.

Comment: Thank you very much, one last question how if it's not particle but preposition? Could we still generally exchange the position?

Comment: *"Will you **look after** my little sister while I'm in the hospital?"*  In this example *after* is not a particle.  It's just a regular preposition, and we can't move *after* to the end.  *\*"Will you **look** my little sister **after** while I'm in the hospital?"* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Please note that you say "Turn down for what?" not "Turn for what down?"

Comment: A number of my formerly Yiddish speaking ancestors would still tell you to "throw down the stairs my hat and coat" :)

Answer (score 4):

These kind of phrasal verbs are called **separable**.

Some transitive phrasal verbs are separable, which means there are two possible positions for the object.

> 1.- *He took off **his jacket**.*
>    2.- *He took **his jacket** off.*

However when the object is a pronoun, it always goes between the two parts of a separable verb.

> 1.- *He took **it** off.*
>    2.- *He took o̶f̶f̶ ̶i̶t̶.*

Comment: For some reason, I can't put the second example right below the first one. I don't know how to do it. If someone knows, please show how to do so, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "he"?

Comment: Of course! Didn't see that.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to be technical, this phrase has entered the English Language due to its widespread use (because *everyone* has a radio nowadays, right?).  Phrases that enter like this don't usually follow normal grammatical rules or common sense (e.g. *slow down* vs *slow up*).

In other words, either way is acceptable.