# Whether to move something over or move over something?

Tags: word-usage

I ran across the sentence written by an American guy in his published book, saying

> Could you move one seat over?

Do you alternatively say

> Could you move over one 
>   seat?

Comment: Related: [“turn down the volume” or “turn the volume down”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73264/turn-down-the-volume-or-turn-the-volume-down-phrasal-verb-structure)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that *both* are *idiomatic*. If you analyse each of them they can seem like they are a request for the *seat itself* to be moved!

I would say that the second is the one which is correct:

> Could you move over one seat?

This request identifies the *subject*, the *action*, and the *direction/measurement* in that order. You want the person ("you") to "move over" by "one seat".

> Could you move one seat over?

Under scrutiny this version sounds more like you are asking for a seat to be moved because it groups the seat and the request to move. But as I said, it is idiomatically used and would almost certainly be understood.

Comment: Your answer fully clarifies my question.  Thanks a lot.