# (Run him over / Run over him) Which is correct?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, adverbs

> He was **run over** by a truck.

So, in this case which is correct?

> a. A truck **ran** him **over**. 
>   b. A truck **ran over** him.

I think 'over' in 'a' sentence is adverb and 'over' in 'b' sentence is preposition, am I right? So, which is correct between a and b?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [“turn down the volume” or “turn the volume down” - phrasal verb structure](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73264/turn-down-the-volume-or-turn-the-volume-down-phrasal-verb-structure)

Comment: @Em.♦ So, you say 'b' is not correct? but I saw many case of 'b', I don't think it is the same case. If you google "ran over him", you will see many of them.

Comment: No, I am not saying anything about right or wrong. I’m just trying to give you/future readers more information. Let’s wait for proper answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

> **ran over him**

... is the correct form.

"To run over" is a verb phrase, and therefore, is best kept as is. There are cases where you can add words in the middle but this isn't one.