# What is the difference between "Write it down" and "Write down it"?

Tags: word-usage

Oh hi! thanks for reading this question.

I'm an English learner and I just want to know what's the difference between "Write it down" and "Write down it"?.

Can you elaborate?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [“turn down the volume” or “turn the volume down” - phrasal verb structure](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73264/turn-down-the-volume-or-turn-the-volume-down-phrasal-verb-structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the latter is ungrammatical. In a prepositional verb, an unstressed pronoun such as "it" must directly follow the verb. This is explained in Huddleston & Pullum (2005: 144):

> One general constraint on the order 'particle + object' is that it is *inadmissible if the object has the form of an **unstressed personal pronoun*** (italic mine). For example, we can replace *the suitcase* by unstressed *it* in [36ia] but not in [iia]:
>
> a. She took it off 
> b. * She took off it

Answer (score 1):

Some verbs in English are phrasal verbs, these are formed of a verb and a particle. Usually, the particle can also function as a preposition.  Examples of phrasal verbs are "Turn on" and "get off"

Phrasal verbs can be "separable" or "inseparable".  When a phrasal verb is separable, and the object of the verb is a pronoun, the pronoun is moved between the verb and preposition.  "Turn on" is separable, but "look after" is inseparable.

Examples:

> Turn on the light
> Turn it on
> Look after the child
> Look after her

"Write down" is a separable phrasal verb, so you say

> Write down the sentence.
> Write it down.

There is no rule for telling if a verb is separable or inseparable.  In inseparable verbs the meaning of the preposition is often closer to its usual meaning but this only a rough guide, and doesn't explain every verb.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'write down it' is wrong; we should say ‘write it down’.
You can say ‘write the article down’ or ‘write down the article’. When a phrasal verb follows the pronoun, it should not be separable but if it follows a noun it may or not be separable.